# Polygons formatted in GeoJSON don't appear correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, queue, geojson, cartography

I'm trying to make a map using **d3.js** and three data files:

- a simple **.topojson** file with my base map
- a **.geojson** file with polygonal areas
- a **.csv** file with data (which has a field in common with the **.geojson**)

First, I created my base map with this code:

```
var width = 360,
height = 600,
width2 = 479;

var proj = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([7.76, 48.57])
    .scale(130000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(proj);

var svg = d3.select("#carte").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("strasbourg.json", function(error, base) {

   svg.append("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(base, base.objects.contour).features)
      .attr("class", "fond-stras")
      .attr("d", path);
```

The result was fine (http://raphi.m0le.net/data/BAS/App_d3_strasrk/etape%201.html), so I made my code more complex:

```
var width = 360,
    height = 600,
    width2 = 479;

var proj = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([7.76, 48.57])
    .scale(130000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

// This array will be used to the next choropleth

var couleurs = ['rgb(165,15,21)','rgb(222,45,38)','rgb(251,106,74)',
    'rgb(252,146,114)','rgb(252,187,161)','rgb(254,229,217)'];

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(proj);

var svg = d3.select("#carte").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// I use queue.v1.min.js to load my .topojson, .geojson and .csv

queue()
    .defer(d3.json,"strasbourg.json")
    .defer(d3.json, "chute_ries.json")
    .defer(d3.csv, "progression_riesk.csv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error,base,areas,results) {

// I declare my base map like before, it works always fine

  svg.append("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(base, base.objects.contour).features)
      .attr("class", "fond-stras")
      .attr("d", path);

// the problematic part begins here :

  svg.append("g").attr("class","areas")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(areas.features)
        .enter()
          .append("path")
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", path)
// I write this to test an automatic colouring
          .attr("fill", function(d,i){
              if (results[i].diff_ries<-23){
            return couleurs[0]
          }
          else {return couleurs[4]

          }
        })
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as you will see here: http://raphi.m0le.net/data/BAS/App_d3_strasrk/etape%202.html

Despite my efforts, I have not been able to get this to work. My **.geojson** was created with QGis, so I guess that it respects the Right-Hand-Rule.

My console does not display any errors so I haven't been able to determine what is wrong. I suspect that it could be the `data()` declaration, but I've seen several examples where it was written like this with **.geojson** data and worked perfectly.

Comment: The coordinates in you geojson don't look suitable for the mercator projection to me. You've probably used the wrong projection when creating the file.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Lars ! I've just tried to resave my .geojson with the WGS84 projection on QGis, but it still doesn't work :-(...

Comment: [This question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/39277/how-to-create-a-geojson-that-works-with-d3) may help.

Comment: You were right Lars, I had areas with a wrong projection, [now the map works fine](http://raphi.m0le.net/data/BAS/App_d3_strasrk/carte_ip.html). Thanks again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little tricky, but the problem comes from the projection of my original file : Lambert-93 (a french reference) instead of the Mercator precised in the script !

I resaved the file with a Mercator projection, and all worked perkectly fine !